# GetMap() return null on Android API > 15 but works perfectly fine on equal or lower version

Tags: android, api, nullpointerexception, maps, versions

I call a map which is inside a fragment. It works on my smartphone which is API 15 (Jelly Bean) but not on higher API.
I get a NullPointerException and the application crashes. I think that the problem comes from the layout that is not ready when I try getMap(). I tried all kind of things but nothing worked.
I also saw that the getMap() method has been recently deprecated.

Here is the part of my codes

The **layout** :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3.fragments.LocationFragment">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        tools:context="fr.irseem.ping32.MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The **LocationFragment** where I put the map :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);

    // Initializing array List
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_view);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((MapFragment) this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view))
                .getMap();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {

            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude());
                    MarkerOptions currentLocationMarkOpt = new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("My location");

                    // on remplace le marqueur par notre nouvelle position
                    currentLocationMark.setPosition(currentLocation);
                    //currentLocationMark = mMap.addMarker(currentLocationMarkOpt);

                    markerPoints.add(1, currentLocation);

                    updateItinerary();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the **Logcat** :

```
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3, PID: 11418
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3.fragments.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:149)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-20 15:24:25.861 11418-11418/fr.irseem.ping32.smartp3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: From a quick look on your logcat, it seems rather more that `mapFragment` is null.

Comment: Yes, but **it is only null on device with API higher than 15**, otherwise it works perfectly. I think that's because I call the method inside OnCreateView but I don't understand why it works with some smartphones, and why it doesn't work with others

Comment: according to this https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMap() -- the getMap() is deprecated

Comment: Have you created different layouts for different api levels?

Comment: No. Thanks for the idea, what should I use in the layout instead of the MapFragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **getMapAsync(this)** instead of **getMap()**.

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view));
mMap.getMapAsync(this);
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

You can probably check the Google documentation on handling maps.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment?hl=en

You can try using the below code for creating markers.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
Origin_Map = extras.getString(MainActivity.ORIGIN_MAP);
Destination_Map = extras.getString(MainActivity.DESTINATION_MAP);
Addr_Origin = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Origin_Map, 1);
Addr_Dest = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Destination_Map, 1);
if (Addr_Origin.size() > 0) {
            latitude_origin = Addr_Origin.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude_origin = Addr_Origin.get(0).getLongitude();
        }
        if (Addr_Dest.size() > 0) {
            latitude_destination = Addr_Dest.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude_destination = Addr_Dest.get(0).getLongitude();
        }
        Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude_origin, longitude_origin)).title(Origin_Map).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        Marker m2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude_destination, longitude_destination)).title(Destination_Map).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        PolylineOptions flightpath = new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(latitude_origin, longitude_origin)).add(new LatLng(latitude_destination, longitude_destination));
        Polyline flightpath_polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(flightpath.width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
```

Comment: Thanks but mMap  is a GoogleMap type not a MapFragment. I need it that way to use markers.

Comment: True, but a GoogleMap must be acquired using getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback). This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view.
You can further use the GoogleMap to create markers and polylines. See my edit above.

Comment: Thanks it works well. But now I can't manage to set a location listener to update a route between the two markers (one of the marker is the location of the user). Do you know how can I put in in the OnMapReady() ?